# How to undo saved file after closing in sublime text 3

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, ubuntu-18.04

I am in a huge trouble.

I have all my important notes in one of my sublime file. Now I opened sublime and clear all that notes and closed it again by mistake. Now I have to undo to get all that notes again and since I have closed the sublime it is headache for me to retrieve those changes. **Please help**

Comment: Now your changes are probably "lost" (i.e. you need to run some kind of file-recovery software). Since you've closed sublime, the old contents of the file is __no more__ in the memory (but there's still some chance that it can be recovered). Of course, if you keep the notes in a VCS (and committed the file into it), there is no problem here, since you can rollback all the changes.

Comment: @trolley813 Could you please let me know which software I can use to retrieve those changes? Please.

Comment: For example, Recuva by CCleaner: https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva

Comment: @trolley813 I am on ubuntu

Comment: That's even better, since you probably use `ext4` file system (and it's easier to undelete files from here). You can probably try ext4magic or extundelete (I don't know if they're available in the vanilla repositories, or one has to add an external one).

Comment: maybe in the future sync your notes in google drive.it has version control. or maybe use github or other git software. try to keep important things on at least two places in the cloud and locally.

Comment: @TreantBG I will strictly follow your advice. But what to do now?